# How to set offset for VertexAttribPointer with rust?

Tags: opengl, rust

I was playing around with `gl-rs` and in the original opengl tutorial they set `VertexAttribPointer` and it's offset with:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3* sizeof(float)));
```

With the `gl-rs` I can't understand how to set offset of `(void*)(3* sizeof(float)`. I can set `(void*)0` with :

```
gl::VertexAttribPointer(
            0,         
            3,        
            gl::FLOAT, 
            gl::FALSE, 
            (6 * std::mem::size_of::<f32>()) as gl::types::GLint, 
            std::ptr::null(),                                     // offset 
        );
```

How do I set different values like `(void*)(3* sizeof(float)` for the offset? I am not familiar with C so explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last parameter (offset) has to be cast to `*const gl::types::GLvoid`:

```js
gl::VertexAttribPointer(
            1,
            3,
            gl::FLOAT,
            gl::FALSE,
            (6 * std::mem::size_of::<f32>()) as gl::types::GLint,
            (3 * std::mem::size_of::<f32>()) as *const gl::types::GLvoid
        );
```

<sub>See also

[glVertexAttribPointer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml)

[Rust and OpenGL from scratch - Vertex Attribute Format](http://nercury.github.io/rust/opengl/tutorial/2018/06/27/opengl-in-rust-from-scratch-09-vertex-attribute-format.html)</sub>